# Can't run .net core Web API using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting the following an error in visual studio 2015 while running the asp.net core Web API project in my windows 7 64 bit machine.

> The program '[15460] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
>   The program '[16176] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
>   The program '[15432] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[10296] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Regards,
Parthiban

Comment: Try running as [Your project name] instead of IIS Express

Comment: In the single solution, I have two Web API projects. I want to run the two project at a time via multiple startup projects setting. In this situation I have faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Run them both as standalone executables instead of using IIS. VS supports multiple startup and debugging so it wont disrupt your debugging workflow.